# Loop through json keys in python

Tags: python, json

So... I was making a discord web hook caller, and I was making the JSON reader to know what web hooks it has to send. I wanted to print the message that it would send and the following happened: It wasn't giving me an output.
My code:

main.py:

```
import json
from collections import Counter
#import requests

with open('data.json') as json_file:
    data = json.load(json_file)
    for hallo in range(0, len(data) - 1):
        stringSmall = "<:" + data[str(hallo + 1)]['emojiName'] + ":" + data[str(hallo + 1)]['serverID'] + ">"
        print(stringSmall)
```

data.json:

```
{
    "1": {
        "webhookURL": "some.webhook.url/path/to/handler",
        "emojiName": "7777",
        "emojiID": "8888",
        "serverID": "999999999999999999"
    }
}
```

I want to print a composition of:

> "<:" + {One of the multiple emoji names(I have more of the shown abobe)} + ":" + {One of the multiple server IDs) + ">"

The output that I want should look like: <:7777:999999999999999999>
But I simply got no output

Please help, I'm struggling to think what is happening

Comment: Read the [documentation on `range()`](https://docs.python.org/3.3/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=range#range). It goes from `start` to `end`, but does not include `end`. When `len(data)` is `1`, `range(0, len(data) - 1)` will have zero elements. [How to debug small programs.](//ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/)
|
[What is a debugger and how can it help me diagnose problems?](//stackoverflow.com/q/25385173/843953). Change the range call to `range(0, len(data))`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `.items()` to iterate over the dictionary:

```
import json
with open('data.json') as json_file:
    data = json.load(json_file)

    for k, values in data.items():
        # k == 1
        stringSmall = "<:" + values['emojiName'] + ":" + values['serverID'] + ">"
        print(stringSmall)
```

Out:

```
<:7777:999999999999999999>
```

Comment: OP's technique of iterating over the `range()` and selecting specific elements ensures the same order every time. Given dicts are unordered, would iterating over `items()` give the same order every time?

Comment: Since Python3.7 `dicts` are ordered.